# wkhtmltopdf or rotativa PDF document security

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

How can we set document security ? i.e how can make below all/some changes to disallow before or after pdf generates, available for download ?

Have a look image here for exact detail. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rnNw.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can wicked\_pdf or wkhtmltopdf generate a protected pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751277/can-wicked-pdf-or-wkhtmltopdf-generate-a-protected-pdf)

Comment: Thanks for comment.

Well Above solution just provides PDF with password protected. My requirements is bit different as i don't need document as password protected but document must not allow printing, sign, edit etc etc as mentioned in attached screenshot.